# charge specific child component existing in a loop

Tags: angular, components

I have two nested components, each of which has a for loop. When I click on a specific element of the first component I show the list of its children.

Right now, all the list of users is initialized by default, which causes slowness in the page.

How can I show charge just list of user corresponding to the selected agency?

```
<ng-container>
  <div *ngFor="let group of refgroupList">
    <div class="content-agences" >
      <div>
        <input id="{{ 'toggle' + group.code }}" type="checkbox" class="toggle">
        <label id="{{ 'label' + group.code }}" for="{{ 'toggle' + group.code }}" class="title-agencie" (click)="onClick(group.code)">{{ group.label }}</label>
        <section class="expand">
            <plmc-cutomer [groupCode]="group.code" [userListResult]="userListResult"></plmc-cutomer>
          </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngTemplate and ngIf, like this.

```
<div *ngFor="let group of groups">
  <table class="groups-dispo" id="{{ 'tab' + group.registrationNumber }}">
    <tr class="line-group" *ngIf="group.usualName != '' ">
      <td class="title-tab-group" (click)="group.clicked = !group.clicked">{{group.usualName}}</td>
      <ng-template [ngIf]="group.clicked">
        <td *ngFor="let vacation of getVacation(group.vacation)" [ngClass]="vacation ? 'disponible' : 'indisponible'" (click)="associategroupTask('group-task', group)"></td>
      </ng-template>  
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

onClick in td.title-tab-group will toggle a property(clicked) to you know when show or hide the sibling component.

ng-template will show a list of vacation when a property(clicked) is true